# How to get opening balance on the first record given accumulated balance in power query

Tags: powerquery

Given table below, where the starting date is variable, as it can be start from any date for a month:

- Component | Type | Date   | AccumulateBalance
- A         | PO   | 31 Jan | 240
- A         | PO   | 1 Feb  | 240
- B         | PO   | 28 Jan | 300
- B         | PO   | 29 Jan | 300
- A         | SO   | 31 Jan | 100
- A         | SO   | 1 Feb  | 100

I need to calculate the first opening balance given only the accumulated Balance, and it is reset by Component + Type

- Component | Type | Date   | OpenBalance
- A         | PO   | 31 Jan | 240
- A         | PO   | 1 Feb  | 0
- B         | PO   | 28 Jan | 300
- B         | PO   | 29 Jan | 0
- A         | SO   | 31 Jan | 100
- A         | SO   | 1 Feb  | 0

Any helps or advice will be very much appreciated!

Thank you 
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bit of custom PowerQuery code pasted into home ... advanced editor...

Assuming data is loaded into Table1, the third row will add a column that is the minimum date of all rows with matching Component and Type.  The fourth row then checks to see if the current row's date matches the minimum; if so it shows the balance, otherwise zero

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Component", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"AccumulateBalance", Int64.Type}}),
AddMinDateColumn = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Earliest Date", (thisrow) => List.Min(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Component] = thisrow[Component] and [Type] = thisrow[Type])[Date]), type date),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(AddMinDateColumn, "OpenBalance", each if [Date]=[Earliest Date] then [AccumulateBalance] else 0)
in #"Added Custom"
```

another way is to select the Component and Type columns, and Group them, using minimum of Date column and AllRows. If you expand the AccumulateBalance column and remove duplicates, that will give you a table of the minimum dates and their values. You can then merge it back into original table matching on Component, Type, and Date, and expand the Balance field. Sample below which can be pasted into Home...advanced editor...  Assumes data is loaded into Table1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Component", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"AccumulateBalance", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Component", "Type"}, {{"MinDate", each List.Min([Date]), type date}, {"Data", each _, type table}}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Data", {"AccumulateBalance"}, {"Data.AccumulateBalance"}),
Table2= Table.Distinct(#"Expanded Data"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"Component", "Type", "Date"},Table2,{"Component", "Type", "MinDate"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Data.AccumulateBalance"}, {"OpeningBalance"})
in #"Expanded Table2"
```